# blevesearch how to paginate results?

Tags: go, full-text-search, bleve

I'm trying to integrate [blevesearch](https://godoc.org/github.com/blevesearch/bleve#SearchRequest) in my app. How am I supposed to implement pagination? I can't find any param to indicate the page number, per-page limit or cursor in the docs.

Comment: The docs on that struct say: "Size/From describe how much and which part of the result set to return". Does that not work? There's also `NewSearchRequestOptions` to fill those fields in for you.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue while trying to add pagination to the [gozim project](https://github.com/akhenakh/gozim), and I used JimB's comment to find a solution.  I updated this:

```
queryString := r.FormValue("search_data")
query := bleve.NewQueryStringQuery(queryString)
search := bleve.NewSearchRequest(query)
```

To this:

```
queryString := r.FormValue("search_data")
pageString := r.FormValue("page")
pageNumber, _ := strconv.Atoi(pageString)
itemCount := 20
from := itemCount * pageNumber
query := bleve.NewQueryStringQuery(queryString)
search := bleve.NewSearchRequestOptions(query, itemCount, from, false)
```

And it appears to be working correctly.